# Google Identity One Tap in Jetpack Compose not working

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I have successfully implemented all the code from this article (https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) into my app and fixed all the bugs. However, the feature is not working as expected. When I press the button, nothing pops up.

I have already checked the web client ID and tried reconnecting to Firebase, as well as creating a new Firebase project, but none of these solutions have worked. What else might I be missing?

After successfully signing in, I would like to access the Gmail API. What resources can help me achieve this goal?

Comment: If nothing pops up, most likely you aren't signed in with Google on the device. Please check the logcat for errors. Btw, I have just updated the entire project and pushed it on GitHub.

Comment: There is no error in logcat, but instead "app_time_stats: avg=181.11ms min=9.28ms max=8750.92ms count=53"
And what do you mean by you aren't signed in with Google on the device? Do I need to have signed in first in order to use this one-tap sign-in? if so, Is there a way that I can modify it so I can sign by asking the user to input their email and password in the app?

Comment: Yes, if you launch the app on a device, the user should be authenticated with Google on that device. To answer your last question, yes, you can but using the old way for implementing it.

Comment: When you say 'the old way', are you referring to the legacy approach or something else? Most of the approaches I found can't really work with jetpack compose. I am new to Android development, so I would appreciate it if you could provide me with more insight.

Comment: Actually, I just found your other article (https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-email-and-password-in-jetpack-compose-bd70ca56ea91) and will try that instead.

Comment: Ok, give it a try and tel me if you solved the issue.